# Simple Injector unable to inject dependencies in Web API controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am attempting to do some basic constructor DI with Simple Injector, and it seems that it is unable to resolve the dependencies for Web API controllers.

- I have an API controller in an "API" folder, that is outside the "Controllers" folder.
- I have also tried placing it within the "Controllers" folder, but
  that did not seem to make much of a difference. The stack trace that
  I receive is similar to the one presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347152/simpleinjector-injection-does-not-work-with-mvc-4-asp-net-web-api).
- I am using a fresh install of the "Simple Injector MVC Integration Quick Start" NuGet Package (v. 2.1.0).
- I have the base `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` from the documentation, which is also the same as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254292/does-simple-injector-supports-mvc-4-asp-net-web-api).
- I am using Entity Framework, and have looked at the [discussion
  thread](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/363935) about changes to correctly load the context.

This does not
   seem to be a problem, but I still receive the following error:

> Type 'MyProject.API.ArticleController' does not have a default
>   constructor
>
> System.ArgumentException at
>
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

It would be appreciated if someone could offer me some suggestions, on whether anything should be modified from its current state/call order.

ArticleController (basic structure):

```
public class ArticleController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IArticleRepository articleRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
    private readonly IReleaseRepository releaseRepository;

    public ArticleController(IArticleRepository articleRepository, IUserRepository userRepository, IReleaseRepository releaseRepository)
    {
        this.articleRepository = articleRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.releaseRepository = releaseRepository;
    }

    // GET api/Article
    public IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles(){ // code }

    // GET api/Article/5
    public Article GetArticle(int id){ // code }

    // PUT api/Article/5
    public HttpResponseMessage PutArticle(int id, Article article){ // code }

    // POST api/Article
    public HttpResponseMessage PostArticle(ArticleModel article){ // code }

    // DELETE api/Article/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteArticle(int id){ // code }
}
```

SimpleInjectorInitializer:

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();
        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IArticleRepository, ArticleRepository>();
        container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        container.Register<IReleaseRepository, ReleaseRepository>();
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private void ConfigureApi()
    {
        // Create the container as usual.
        var container = new Container();

        // Verify the container configuration
        // container.Verify();

        // Register the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
                new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        ConfigureApi();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ConfigureApi` method is actually run? Did you set a break point in it?

Comment: Any reason why you create a separate `Container` instance for your Web API configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is run. I have a break point set on the line that sets the DependencyResolver on the GlobalConfiguration. If you mean within the Global.asax.cs, then I was following this guide (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver), to see if it would resolve my issue. However, it did not seem to.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**TLTR:** the problem is caused by the implicit way Web API handles resolving controller types; register your Web API controllers explicitly and you'll see where the problem is.

Here is a step by step what is happening under the covers:

1. The `System.Web.Http.DefaultHttpControllerActivator` calls into the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` and requests the creation of an API controller.
2. `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` forwards that call to the `SimpleInjector.Container` instance.
3. That `Container` instance however, does not have any explicit registrations for that API Controller (since you supplied an empty container to the resolver).
4. Since there is no explicit registration, the container tries to do a last minute registration for that type.
5. That Controller type however depends on interfaces that can't be resolved because they are not registered in the container (remember, your container is empty).
6. Although the container would normally throw an exception, null is returned in this case, because  the type is requested through the `IServiceProvider.GetService` method and the type was not registered explictly.
7. The `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver`'s `GetService` method will return `null` as well, since it's by definition that it should return null; It should return null when no registration exists (which currently is the case).
8. Since the `DependencyResolver` returned null, `DefaultHttpControllerActivator` will fall back to its default behavior, which means creating that type itself, but this requires the controller to have a default constructor.

Long story short, the problem is caused by the implicit way Web API handles resolving controller types.

So the solution here is to:

1. Have only one single `Container` in your web application. This prevents all sorts of trouble and complication of your configuration.
2. Register all Web API Controllers explicitly in the container. Registering controllers explicitly will ensure that Simple Injector will throw an exception when a controller can't be resolved. Besides, this allows you to call `container.Verify()` which will make the application fail during startup when the configuration is invalid (a [verifiable configuration is important](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#verify-the-container-s-configuration)). And this also allows you to [diagnose the configuration](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) which gives you even more confidence about the correctness of your configuration.

My [advice is to place MVC and Web API in their own project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494920/what-is-the-difference-between-dependencyresolver-setresolver-and-httpconfigurat/15495934#15495934). This will make things much easier.

Registering all Web API controllers can be done with the following code:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

**UPDATE:**

Because this error is so common, newer versions of the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` class will simply **never** return `null` when a controller type is requested. Instead it will throw a descriptive error. Because of this you should never see error anymore, as long as you use the official `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Where exactly should I place this method? Is it implied that I should make a new class, and implement it as an extension method of the Container?

Comment: It's an extension method. You can place it in any static class so you can do `container.RegisterApiControllers()` from within your Composition Root.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to set the **GlobalConfiguration** `DependencyResolver` within the `SimpleInitializer`? Or should that be kept within the Global.asax.cs? The documentation (http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20API%20Integration) suggests that container creation and service/resource registration should be done within `Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs, but comments in `InitializeContainer()` also seem to suggest that registration should happen there.

Comment: There is no harm in placing this in the `SimpleInjectorInitiazer`.

Comment: Is it the same to use GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver().GetControllerTypes() ? (instead of searching the assembly with the LINQ code you used?

Comment: @diegohb: Good catch. Using the HttpControllerTypeResolve would be better. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Steven can i get your attention on this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499668/make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless-public-constructor-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Following setups work for me:

1) include **Unity.WebAPI** from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/
2) in **UnityConfig**

```
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            // **** Important note -----
            // register all your components with the container here
            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();


            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc5.UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

3) in **Global.asax** file

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            }
        }
```

---

### Getting started with Unity.WebAPI

To get started, just add a call to UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() in the Application_Start method of Global.asax.cs 
and the Web API framework will then use the Unity.WebAPI DependencyResolver to resolve your components.

e.g.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();                           // <----- Add this line
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
  }           
}
```

Add your Unity registrations in the RegisterComponents method of the UnityConfig class. All components that implement IDisposable should be 
registered with the HierarchicalLifetimeManager to ensure that they are properly disposed at the end of the request.