# "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to constructors. Please explain why it's giving me the following error:

```
"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

Here I have 1 Interface (IRepo) 1 Class File (Repo)
IRepo.cs

```
public interface IRepo
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee();
        IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployee(int id);
    }
```

**Repo.cs**

```
Ctxdb _db = null;
        public Repo(Ctxdb db)
        {
            this._db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee()
        {
           //  
        }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
IRepo _ObjRepo = null;

        public HomeController(Repo ObjRepo)
        {

            _ObjRepo = ObjRepo;
        }

        [Route("GetEmp")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetDat()
        {
            var x = _ObjRepo.GetEmployee();
            if (x != null)
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, x);
            else
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,"Not Implemented");
        }
```

Comment: just have a parameterless constructor in your controller.

Comment: But im Confussing wat its could u plz Give me any Hint

Comment: That's pretty clear: you need to create a public constructor with no parameters... Example: `public HomeController()`Also, there are plenty of questions with answers that talk about this problem. Please refer to these posts

Comment: Ya I Created public HomeController(Repo ObjRepo)
        {

            _ObjRepo = ObjRepo;
        }  In this way but how can  i invok it

Comment: Perhpas this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254189/make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless-public-constructor-error?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you wan't to achieve dependency injection. If that's correct than you should do three tings:

1. Change your Constructor to use an `IRepo` instead of `Repo`
2. Install and configure an IoC Container like AutoFac or Unity
3. Configure the ASP.NET Web API Dependency Resolver

There is a great tutorial in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).