# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have integrated dependency injection with code first entity framework. But when I call method of api that time I am getting error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DrugController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

stackTrace:

```
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

innerException:

> System.ArgumentException: Type 'SA_Admin.Controllers.DrugController' does not have a default constructor

stackTrace:

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

but when I remove constructor with parameter then I can call with out error.

I cross check every file but does not getting error. What I am missing? Also all method of account working perfectly because controller is with out constructor.

Project is only web api project. I did not add mvc.

I used Autofac DI nuget package.

suggest me solution.

Startup.cs

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        IoCConfig.RegisterDependencies();
    }
```

IOCConfig.cs

```
public class IoCConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For more info see
    /// :http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        #region Create the builder 
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        #endregion

        #region Register all authentication dependencies
        // REGISTER DEPENDENCIES
        builder.RegisterType<SA_AdminEntities>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest(); 
        #endregion   

        #region Register all web api controllers for the assembly
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        #endregion

        #region Register modules
        builder.RegisterModule(new BusinessLogicInstaller());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ReposInstaller());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ServicesInstaller());
        #endregion 

        #region Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac
        var container = builder.Build(); 
        //for WebApi
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ServiceInstaller.cs

```
public class ServicesInstaller : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    { 
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DrugService).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

RepoInstaller.cs

```
public class ReposInstaller : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        #region Repositories 
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DrugRepo).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repo"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        #endregion  
    }

}
```

BusinessLogicInstaller.cs

```
public class BusinessLogicInstaller : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ParamEncryption>().As<IParamEncryption>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<Mapper>().As<IMapper>().InstancePerRequest(); 
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Filters.Add(new ErrorLogApiHandler());

        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver
        {
            ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint) }
        };
        //removes xml formatter
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        //enable json formatters
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        //TODO Turn off move to dev and prod
        //enable cors
        //config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        //add api versioning 
        ApiVersion apiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        config.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            //will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;

            //TODO define api controllers here with versions
            //Like below Example
            options.Conventions.Controller<DrugController>().HasApiVersion(apiVersion);

        });

        //enable attribute routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Public")]
public class DrugController : ApiController
{
    #region Variables
    private readonly IDrugService drugService;

    private readonly IPersistService persistService;        
    private readonly IParamEncryption encryptor;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public DrugController(IDrugService drugService, IPersistService persistService, IParamEncryption encryptor)
    {
        this.drugService = drugService; 
        this.persistService = persistService; 
        this.encryptor = encryptor;
    }

    [Route("Drugs")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Drugs()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp;
        try
        {
            var lstdrugs = drugService.GetDrugs(xx => true);
            resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstdrugs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resp = Request.CustomHandleError(ex);
        }

        return ResponseMessage(resp);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: There are many DI libraries and even more branches of ASP.NET. You should add the names and version numbers to your question.

Comment: I used Autofac DI nuget package.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same error you would get if you didn't register one of the parameters with the autofac container. The actual error may be several layers of inner exceptions down. I only see IParamEncryption registered. Register the other two interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

**See this link to solve your problem, mainly it is DI registration and resolver problem.**

See the below post for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257085/7404931