# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XXXXController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I  have created a asp.net web api project and implemented the below HTTP GET method in `AccountController` and the related service method & repository method in `AccountService` & `AccountRepository` respectively.

```
// WEB API 
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    [HttpGet, ActionName("UserProfile")]
    public JsonResult<decimal> GetUserSalary(int userID)
    {
        var account = _accountService.GetUserSalary(userID);
        if (account != null)
        {
            return Json(account.Salary);
        }
        return Json(0);
    }
}
```

**Service / Business Layer**

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    decimal GetUserSalary(int userId);
}

public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    readonly IAccountRepository _accountRepository = new AccountRepository();

    public decimal GetUserSalary(int userId)
    {
        return _accountRepository.GetUserSalary(userId);
    }
}
```

**Repository / Data Access Layer**

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    decimal GetUserSalary(int userId);
}

public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    public decimal GetUserSalary(int userId)
    {
        using (var db = new AccountEntities())
        {
            var account = (from b in db.UserAccounts where b.UserID == userId select b).FirstOrDefault();
            if (account != null)
            {
                return account.Salary;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**UnityConfig**

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IAccountService, AccountService>();
        container.RegisterType<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

But when I invoke the API method `GetUserSalary()` I get an error saying

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: Are you using Owin or classic asp.net flow i.e Startup.cs or Global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you did not forget to register Unity IoC container itself:

- if you use ASP.NET Framework it could be - Global.asax or Startap.cs (Owin) via `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()` method.
- if you use ASP.NET Core then in the Startup.cs file (I was unable to find official guides for its configuting)

Comment: I have added UnityConfig.RegisterComponents() to Global.asax under Application_Start(). It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Your current constructor has parameters (or args if you prefer).

see:

```
public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
{
    _accountService = accountService;
}
```

> All you need to do is add a "Parameter-less Constructor" into the controller as well.

```
public AccountController()
{
}
```

Parameter-less constructors are usually above the ones that have params, though as far as I am aware this is only due to standards not any actual effect(s) it may cause.

> There is also an already existing issue/question similar to this I will link below that may provide further details.

[Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254189/make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless-public-constructor-error?rq=1)

Comment: "All you need to do is add a "Parameter-less Constructor" into the controller as well." -> not if he depends on `IAccountService accountService`. He should check the DI registration

Comment: @PeterBons How do we do that? Can you share a code?

Comment: I have added above code. But it returns null exception for _accountService.