# Web API Nunit Tests not injecting dependencies

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, nunit, simple-injector

When trying to unit test my web api project I am getting the error

> {[Message, An error has occurred.]}
>   ExceptionMessage, An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ExampleController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>   {[ExceptionType, System.InvalidOperationException]}
>   {[StackTrace,    at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
>      at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()]}
>   {[InnerException, System.Web.Http.HttpError]}

Unit Test:

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void TestsSetup()
{
    _server = HttpRequestHelper.SetupHttpServerDefault();
}

[Test]
public void CanGetAllAddresses()
{
    var client = new HttpClient(_server);

    var request = HttpRequestHelper.CreateRequest("memory/address", HttpMethod.Get, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyUser"], string.Empty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretUser"]);
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(response.Content);
    }
}
```

I am registering my controllers within an nunit `TestFixtureSetUp` function that involves this logic:

```
public static HttpServer SetupHttpServerDefault()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "memory/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IAddressService, AddressService>();
    var services = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services;
    var controllerTypes = services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver().
            GetControllerTypes(services.GetAssembliesResolver());
    foreach (var controllerType in controllerTypes)
    {
      var registration = Lifestyle.Transient.
          CreateRegistration(controllerType, container);

      container.AddRegistration(controllerType, registration);

      registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning
                   (DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, "");
    }
    container.Verify();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new 
                    SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    return new HttpServer(config);
}
```

My address controller starts out like this:

```
public class AddressController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAddressService _addressService;

    public AddressController(IAddressService addressService)
    {
        _addressService = addressService;
    }
}
```

When removing the controller parameters I am able to debug into the controller which tells me I am not injecting the dependencies into the controller correctly.  I've looked over this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908019/simple-injector-unable-to-inject-dependencies-in-web-api-controllers) that seems similar but I am unfamiliar with how I would explicitly declare my controllers.  I tried using a similar method to my services but I did not work.

Comment: Please show the test code too.

Comment: @qujck test code added.

Comment: is the problem caused by referencing `GlobalConfiguration` and not doing everything in the `config` variable you are creating the `HttpServer` from?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: @Steven full stack trace has been added to the Exception section at the top of the question.  Also, I wanted you both to be aware that I get the exception at the line `using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)` in the controller.

Comment: That can't be the complete exception information. This is the stack trace of the inner most exception. Please add the rest.

Comment: @Steven I have everything that was available in the stack trace.  I am viewing this on response.Content.Value.  If there is somewhere I should look, please let me know.  thanks!

Comment: @qujck I tried switching my references over like you suggested and the problem that I was having on my last post came back.  My service references all starting to come back null.  That's not to say I'm not doing multiple things wrong but I wasn't able to get the services working again with your above mentioned suggestion.

Comment: SimpleInjector won't return null which leads me to believe it's not a problem with the container itself

Comment: The "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor." will only happen when th official SimplInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver isn't called by Web API. Make sure that this resolver is used when running inside a unit test.

Comment: @Steven I reordered the code above to hopefully make it easier to see what I'm doing.  As you can see I am calling `SimplInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` in a `TestFixtureSetUp` function I have created using the line `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);`  Am I missing something?

Comment: Put a break point in the failing test and take a look at the value of `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`. What value does it have? And does that test still fail with the same error when you hit F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my particular problem was actually to register the dependency resolver on both the in memory `HttpServer` that I am creating in the tests and on the `GlobalConfiguration` as well.  Above in the question you'll see the creation of the `config` variable and then this is the code that fixed my issues:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container); 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
                    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Without the `config.DependencyResolver` I wasn't able to connect to my projects controllers via:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
```

And without `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` I wasn't able to contact services locally in my test project.  Hope this helps someone else!