# MVC5 Web API and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to do some DI on Web API 2 without third-party tools.
So, from some examples I've got custom dependency resolver (why there's no integrated one? Strange, even **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** provides nothing):

```
public class DependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public DependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this._serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this._serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
        }

        public void AddService()
        {

        }
    }
```

then created this class:

```
public class ServiceConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyServiceClient>();

            var resolver = new DependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
            config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }

    }
```

and registered it:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(ServiceConfig.Register);
        }
```

But when I'm trying to use it:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private IMyService _myService = null;

        public TestController(IMyService myService)
        {
            _myService = myService;
        }

        public void Get()
        {
            _myService.DoWork();
        }
}
```

I'm getting error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

How to cook this one in right way?

Comment: It breaks on resolving of `TestController` with same message about parameter in constructor.

Comment: Yes, I did it in that way. I've put breakpoints on `GetService` and `GetServices`.
Or you mean something another?

Comment: Nope. It have default constructor, which does not need anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you see happening is related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910758/264697). In short, Web API will call its default `IHttpControllerActivator` implementation to request a new controller instance. That instance will call into your `DependencyResolver.GetService` method. That method will forward the call to MS.DI's `GetService` method. However, since **you didn't register your controllers into the MS.DI container**, it will return `null`. This will cause the default `IHttpControllerActivator` to try to create the controller using reflection, but this requires a default constructor. Since the controller doesn't have one, this results in the rather cryptic exception message.

The quick solution, therefore, is to register your controllers, e.g.:

```
services.AddTransient<TestController>();
```

This, however, will only partly solve your problem because **your `IDependencyResolver` implementation is broken**. It is broken in an ugly way, because it might seem to work at first, but will result in memory leaks, because you **always** resolve from the root container, instead of resolving from a scope. This will cause your resolved controller instances (and other disposable transient components) to stay referenced for the lifetime of your application.

To fix this, you should change your `IDependencyResolver` implementation to the following:

```cs
public class DependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    private readonly IServiceScope scope;

    public DependencyResolver(ServiceProvider provider) => this.provider = provider;

    internal DependencyResolver(IServiceScope scope)
    {
        this.provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope() =>
        new DependencyResolver(provider.CreateScope());

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) => provider.GetService(serviceType);
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type type) => provider.GetServices(type);
    public void Dispose() => scope?.Dispose();
}
```

This implementation will ensure a new `IServiceScope` is created on each web request and services are always resolved from a request; not from the root `IServiceProvider`.

Although this will fix your problems, another implementation might still be benificial.

The `IDependencyResolver` contract is problematic, because it is forced to return `null` when a call to `GetService` doesn't result in the correct resolution of a registration. This means that you will end up with these annoying "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor" errors when you forget to register your controllers.

It is, therefore, much easier to create a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` instead. In that case you can call `GetRequiredService` which will *never* return `null`:

```cs
public class MsDiHttpControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider provider;

    public MsDiHttpControllerActivator(ServiceProvider provider) =>
        this.provider = provider;

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor d, Type controllerType)
    {
        IServiceScope scope = this.provider.CreateScope();
        request.RegisterForDispose(scope); // disposes scope when request ends
        return (IHttpController)scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(controllerType);
    }
}
```

This `MsDiHttpControllerActivator` implementation can be added to the Web API pipeline as follows:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services
  .Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
    new MsDiHttpControllerActivator(services.BuildServiceProvider(true)));
```

This removes the need to have an `IDependencyResolver` implementation. You still need to register your controllers, though:

```
services.AddTransient<TestController>();
```

Also note that I changed this:

```
services.BuildServiceProvider()
```

To this:

```
services.BuildServiceProvider(true)
```

This is a **really important change**; it protects you (for some part) against [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/), which are one of the major problems when using DI Containers. For some obscure reason, the `BuildServiceProvider()` overload defaults to `false`, which means it will not validate your scopes.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. At first I've tried simply to copy-pase your code to project - `MsDiHttpControllerActivator` instead of custom resolver and `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services
  .Replace...` in my *ServiceConfig.Register*, and while all compiles good, I'm now getting `No service for type 'ManagementApp.Controllers.TestController' has been registered.`. Maybe there's a little misunderstanding? I'm trying to do some DI with WCF services in WebAPI project - maybe that's making sense? `MyService` is a WCF, yes.

Comment: Hmm, but it works when I'm adding `services.AddTransient<Controllers.TestController>();`. It's not looks as good and clean solution, so what do you think about that?

Comment: I think you should apply auto-registration (a.k.a. assembly scanning). This prevents you from having to _explicitly_ register each controller. You can do this by reflecting over the assembly to find all controller types and register them in a foreach loop. Or, alternatively, you can pick on of the mature, and feature-rich containers (Autofac, Simple Injector, Castle Windsor, etc), because they _all_ contain features that can do this for you (and much more) out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I've done in my `ServiceConfig` this https://pastebin.com/jtkdSX0E and call it like `services.RegisterApiControllers()` and all works, at least for now. Also I've replaced `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` with `HttpConfiguration config` argument, which provided by `GlobalConfiguration.Configure` in *Global.asax*.